# Is the syntax of assembly instructions processor dependent?

Tags: assembly

I am running a 32 bit C application on 64 bit SUSE Linux.
I just disassembled one of its function in gdb and I see the below assembly at function start i.e. function prologue:

```
0x08048c0e <+0>:     push   %ebp
0x08048c0f <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
```

Assembly instruction mov instruction syntax I guess is:

```
mov <Destination>, <Source>
```

But seeing the assembly code above this seems changed to

```
mov <Source>, <Destination>
```

Is the syntax of assembly instructions processor dependent?

Comment: `gcc`, `gas`, `objdump` etc. use `AT&T` assembly-syntax by default. You can set them to use intel-style syntax with appropriate command-line options: `gcc -masm=intel`, `objdump -M intel`...

Comment: Thanks EOF.
It clears the doubts.

Comment: The title question, *Is the syntax of assembly instructions processor dependent?*, clearly has the answer of "yes" since different processors have different *assembly instructions*. But the *same* processor can have different *assembly syntax* depending upon the assembler tool used.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe as your expectation is known generally as "Intel" syntax while your disassembly i being displayed in AT&T format.

If you are using GDB, you can execute a `set disassembly-flavor intel` command to change it over.  In fact, you can even put this into a `.gdbinit` file in the local directory where you are debugging or, if you want it more generally configured, in your home directory.  It will then be set automatically.